# Рандом из массива с имеющимися undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, случайные-числа

Есть массив.

```
arr[0] = 'undefined';
arr[1] = '16';
arr[2] = 'undefined';
arr[3] = '13';
arr[4] = 'undefined';
arr[5] = 'undefined';
arr[6] = '24';
arr[7] = 'undefined';
```

Как на js выдернуть index элемента, не равного undefined (т.е. из 16,13,24)? Т.е., другими словами, результат может быть либо 1,3,6.

Comment: Вопрос не очень интерейсный, если честно =) Составить массив, содержащий индексы не-undefined элементов, и из него доставать произвольный элемент.

Comment: Дальше.. Еще один поиск делать.. И искать сам индекс по элементу? Как то не очень рационально. Наверняка можно как то в один проход это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока сделал не очень рационально, как мне кажется. В несколько проходов. Но работает. =)

```
    var compact_array = _.compact(table.players);
    compact_array.splice(_.indexOf(compact_array, current_player), 1);
    var rand = _.random(0,compact_array.length-1);
    var player = compact_array[rand];

    result = _.indexOf(table.players, player);
```

Может быть, будут более интересные идеи.